# Transfer Part of Multisite to new Domain

Tags: multisite

I have a multisite on my domain, and I only want to transfer the /support/ install of WordPress to a new domain. Since both installs of WP are combined in the database, how do I separate them so I can move the support site over?

Answer (score 0):

Simple, you don't separate anything because that is going to be terribly complicated. It is advisable to use the standard WordPress import export. See this tutorial:

http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-move-a-site-from-wordpress-multisite-to-single-install/

However, your plugin and theme options will have to be re-set manually after the transfer. If any of those plugins use custom tables, you'd have to figure how the plugin accesses its tables and how is data for that particular blog stored. If everything is custom post types and taxonomies, you are covered.

Comment: The tutorial you provided did not work. I got a bunch of "failed to import" and it didn't transfer any of the extra styling or plugins and plugin data.

I want to move this subsite: www.garrzilla.com/support/



To this domain: www.newdomain.com/support/



But I do not want to move the mainsite: www.garrzilla.com